# oracle insert statement with blob does not work

Tags: oracle, blob

Hi I got a db dump from a mysql testdatabase and I want to insert it into an oracle database with the same table structure but I am getting the following error:

```
[42000][972] ORA-00972: identifier is too long
```

this is the statement

```
INSERT INTO aic.keystore (id, alias, keystore_bytes, password, type, description) VALUES (61, 'test', hextoraw(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null);
```

if I remove the keystore_bytes insertion the insert does complete successfully. So why am I getting an identifier is too long? I haven't any identifiers that exceed 30 characters...

Comment: use `sqlldr` with `hextoraw` function.  Refer https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/load-lob-data-using-sql-loader

Answer (score 0):

You can have a logic of something like below by using **dbms_lob** package.

```
if($stringlen >= 32000) {
        for(my $i = 1; $i <= int(($querylen/32000) + 0.99); $i++) {
            $temptext = substr($sql, 0 + (32000*($i-1)), 32000);
            $sqltext .= "dbms_lob.append(my_sqltext,'$temptext');" . "\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        $sqltext = "my_sqltext := '$sql';" . "\n";
    }
```

Once you get the lob you can insert by using **dbms_lob.write**.